# PHP : Show variable value instead of variable name without concatenating

Tags: php

I tried to get/show the value of **$buttonName** inside a string

**$buttonName** is initialize Null by default and some processing afterwards but even if the **$buttonName** is assigned with a string value the value won't display. e.g

```
$buttonName = "Connect"


echo "Button value is $buttonName";` *//shows '$buttonName' and not "Connect" or whatever value I assigned to it*
```

Concatenating strings from php variables will work though,
but I'd like to know what to configure to make this happening or is this possible? (I know its possible as the document tells us but can't see ways how to display variable value without concatenation).

**ADDED:**

Another strange thing I found is that even if I don't assign any value (Null) the variable name still display ($buttonName) and without getting any error.  I use wamp.

Comment: Are you sure your code is NOT using single quotes? variable interpolation only happens with double-quoted strings.

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau and [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), if I may be pedantic :-)

Comment: Is there any difference in using `{$variable}` vs `'.$variable.'` as far as functionality in the script? It appears to be a cleaner, more simple way to concatenate but is it exactly the same?

Comment: @kcdwayne: `$variable` can only be interpolated if it’s one variable, or array indexing on one variable (but as much array indexing as necessary) or property access of a variable or property of property access of a variable, etcetera, and if the string is double-quoted. But as far as `"Hello, $world"` and `'Hello, ' . $world` — yes, they’re identical in behaviour.

Comment: Raf, your question doesn't make sense. The code you wrote should work as you expect.

Comment: @minitech Good to know. I think I tried `'Hello, $world'` and thought I had to manually concatenate. Double quotes and it works like a charm. Thanks - coding will be much neater (and easier) now.

Comment: @TimothéeGroleau see 'ADDED' update for another strange thing happening

Comment: @Wiseguy  see 'ADDED' update for another strange thing happening

Comment: That code will not produce that output: http://3v4l.org/VmYqd. You have some problem somewhere you're not showing us.

Comment: @minitech Thats wrong: Every expression gets interpolated. http://codepad.viper-7.com/6jJBC2 // #topic http://codepad.viper-7.com/nWdSBG Works as expected

Comment: @deceze sorry if I can't express it in some ways you wanted but thats the core concept of my code. The other processing there are just conditions on what to assign to the variable $buttonName.  I even tried writing separately just the problematic code but still shows the same thing. Otherwise will reinstall wamp.

Comment: Yes, sorry you can't produce an example that would help us diagnose the problem. If [this code](http://3v4l.org/VmYqd) literally does not give the same result on your system, your system is inexplicably foobar'd. If it does give the same result, your example does not show what you're really doing when the problem occurs.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Sorry, I suppose I should have also said “anything using the property access operator”. Saying that “Every expression gets interpolated” is just wrong. http://codepad.viper-7.com/MbJZQ5

Comment: @minitech ... and array-access-operators and function calls and method calls :) But you are right, not everything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

@Raf, your ADDED section adds nothing we didn't already know. It just confirms that there is no variable interpolation happening, which likely means your code is written with SINGLE quotes, like this:

```
$buttonName = "Connect";
echo 'Button value is $buttonName'; // note the SINGLE(!!) quotes around the string!
```

If that is indeed the case, change the single quotes to double quotes and try again:

```
$buttonName = "Connect";
echo "Button value is $buttonName"; // double quotes! interpolation! yeah!
```

If you still have any doubt, open a php console (php -a), and paste the 2 snippets to see the differences.

If you are NOT using single quotes, you need to give us more of your code if you want help.